# Does hotPath reserve specified amount of storage in node

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a static PV spec, using hostPath.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysqlvol
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi #Size of the volume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce #type of access # RWO RWX ROX
  hostPath:
    path: "/tmp/new.txt" #host location
```

In the node I don't see `10Gi` of storage under /tmp.
How is storage reserved for hostPath.

`pvc spec`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysqlvol
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi # < 10Gi
```

`pod spec`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mysqlvol
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

I am able to write data > 10GiB.

```
root@task-pv-pod:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -lh
total 15G
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15G May 22 04:16 bigfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3 May 18 12:04 new.txt
root@task-pv-pod:/usr/share/nginx/html#
```

1. What is the relevance of `10GiB` here as I can write any amount of data in the volume [ 15GiB also works ]
2. Why does PVC creation fail when request size is > 10GiB given the fact that volume is capable of accommodating higher size.

Comment: Can you check this [official doument](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume)
 It says that the configuration specifies a size of 10 gibibytes and an access mode of ReadWriteOnce, which means the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single Node.

Comment: Also importantly to your question, a `hostPath` type volume isn't even attached to a specific node; it uses that directory on whichever node the Pod is running on, and if a Pod is deleted and recreated on a different node it won't see the previous storage.  You probably want some different volume type than `hostPath` (you ideally do not need to manually create PersistentVolumes at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no storage reservation, nor quota.
You declare that the volume is capable of 10GiB and when a PVC with that request is created, it is matched against the declared space.

Comment: which means.. I can write upto 10GiB of data to this volume and not more than that?

Comment: You can write until your physical storage is full.

Comment: So to conclude,In case of static provisioning,  storage specified in PV spec is just to match appropriate PVC when a PVC request comes.  It really does not reserve exact storage .

Comment: Yes, neither reserve nor restrict.